# replace image src text with img

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, src

if a HTML code is

```
<div class="photos">
http://myweb.com/imgs/img1.jpg
https://myweb.com/imgs/img2.gif
http://myweb.com/imgs/img3.png
https://myweb.com/imgs/img4.bmp
</div>
```

how can you via jquery extract any url starting with either `http://` **OR** `https://` and ending with either **.jpg .gif .png or .bmp** and set them as images

```
<div class="photos">
<img src="http://myweb.com/imgs/img1.jpg"/>
<img src="https://myweb.com/imgs/img2.gif"/>
<img src="http://myweb.com/imgs/img3.png"/>
<img src="https://myweb.com/imgs/img4.bmp"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Sound rather simple with `.replace()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it ..

```
$('.photos').html(function(index, html){
    return html.replace(/(http\S+\.(jpg|gif|png|bmp))/gim,'<img src="$1" />');
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/K2nQJ/

Comment: WOW, since when does jQuery accept a callback as the parameter of .html()? It is not even in the documentation. In jsfiddle it doesn't work below version 1.4, so I think that was the milestone, shame I didn't know about that. Thx! +1

Comment: fantastic,I didn't know that the .html() can have a parameter

Comment: @inti, it is in the docs .. http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2 and indeed it was added at 1.4

Comment: @Gaby that is the API documentation (which I was not aware of). I was checking this documentation here: http://docs.jquery.com/Html

Comment: @inti, do you reach those docs manually ? because from the menu they re-direct to the `api.jquery.com` pages..

Comment: I used their search bar for "html" and the above result was given. Stepping back and forth a bit there I suddenly found myself on the api page, but this outdated docs page is still in the system.

Answer (score 3):

Read out the contents of the div. Match the urls and replace the content of the div with the images:

```
$(".photos").each(function() {
    var images = $(this).html(),
        imgs = images.match(/https?:[^\s]+/g),
        html = "";
    for (var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++)
    {
        html += '<img src="'+imgs[i]+'"/>'+"\n";
    }
    $(this).html(html);
});
```

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/inti/ez6WE/

**Edit:** an even better solution is to replace the urls in the original content with the images:

```
$(".photos").each(function() {
    var images = $(this).html(),
        imgs = images.match(/https?:[^\s]+/g);
    for (var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++)
    {
        images = images.replace(imgs[i], '<img src="'+imgs[i]+'"/>');
    }
    $(this).html(images);
});
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/inti/ez6WE/5/

**Edit 2:** to be sure to match only the images you want to display, the regex must be adjusted like this: `/https?:[^\s]+\.(jpg|gif|png|bmp)/g` (good point by @MrMisterMan)

Comment: What if one of the urls isn't an image?

Comment: This is not correct it does not take into account the file extensions, it'll attempt to create an image for `image1.foo`

Comment: Corrected my answer in **Edit 2**. Thx for pointing out, both of you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regular expression that you might be able to use:

`/^(https?://.+?\.(jpg|gif|png|bmp))$/gm` and replace with `<img src="$1" />`

Example of it here: http://regexr.com?2v9r2

Read up on RegExp on the Mozilla Developer Network https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp